# Neural Network using gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

In my neural network model for digit classification 
 cost decrease from 7 to 1.7 and afterward it start increasing again what is possible reason ? I have used learning rate as 0.1 for 5000 iteration , 0.03 for next 5000 iteration
 and 0.001 for next 5000 iteration.
i am getting only 78 % accuracy on training data.
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If the loss decreases, reaches a specific value and starts increasing again, it is mostly due to a *high learning-rate* which causes model to diverge. Though the learning-rates are being lowered after 5000 iterations, the learning rate for the first 5000 iterations might be too high that the model might have drastically diverged by then, that a decrease in learning rates later on might not help it converge. 
Could you try iteratively reducing the learning rates for the first 5000 iterations from, 0.03 (say) and lower and see if the model converges?